# How can I add a talk to my Developer Story?

Tags: support, developer-story

I've done a few talks at meetups and finally did my first conference talk recently. How can I add this to my Developer Story?

Ideally I'd like to add details of the talk and the group I presented it do, links to my slides and video if it exists.

Comment: The closest you can currently add is a Milestone (tooltip: *Add other types of projects, milestones or accomplishments*). You might want to add an external link to your blog/website expanding on this.